# Django: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, django

I need to make a single template which must consist of:

- two inputs with randomly generated integers
- input for user to type in a sum of before-mentioned integers
- button, which checks a user's answer
- button, which creates new random integers

After random creation of integer I mean to pull them to view, so their sum can be checked. But Django throws an exception `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`.

How to fix this issue?

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class SumForm(forms.Form):
    sum = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control"}),
        label='',
        required=False
    )
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SumForm


import random


def index(request):

    form = SumForm(request.POST)
    user_sum = form['sum'].value()

    if 'randomize' in request.POST:
        num1 = random.randint(10, 99)
        num2 = random.randint(10, 99)

    elif 'check' in request.POST:

        num1 = int(request.POST.get('int1'))
        num2 = int(request.POST.get('int2'))

        if int(user_sum) == num1 + num2:
            exclam = 'Right, ' + str(num1 + num2)
        else:
            exclam = 'wrong, ' + str(num1 + num2)

    return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'sum:index' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                <table class="table borderless">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="int1" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value=" {{ num1 }} "></td>
                        <td>+</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="int2" class="form-control" disabled="disabled" value=" {{ num2 }} "></td>
                        <td>=</td>
                        <td> {{ form.as_p }} </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="table borderless">
                    <thead>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><input type="submit" name="randomize" class="btn btn-default" value="New"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary" value="Check"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
                <div class="exclamation">
                    <span> {{ exclam }} </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sum/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['sum.apps.SumConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sum_py/sum/views.py" in index
  19.         num1 = int(request.POST.get('int1'))

Exception Type: TypeError at /sum/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What's the full error with trace? It seems that it would have to be caused by the assignment of `num1` or `num2` though. Have you verified what `request.POST.get('int1')` is returning?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I added the whole traceback of the error, thank you. Sorry, I don't know how to check if data has returned yet

Comment: `request.POST.get('int1')` is returning `None`. You need to check its documentation to see what that means.

Comment: `dict.get(key)` returns `None` if `key` isn't in the dictionary. Your POST request does not contain `int1`.

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform but how can I return generated values, so I can check them?

Comment: @Carcigenicate maybe you can suggest how is it possible to return such generated values?

Comment: just slap `print(request.POST)` into your code and see what is actually in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I just added two hidden inputs, doubled generated data to them and pulled values to the view.

views.py

```
elif 'check' in request.POST:

    num1 = int(request.POST.get("int1", ""))
    num2 = int(request.POST.get("int2", ""))

        if int(user_sum) == int(num1 + num2):
            exclam = 'Right, ' + str(num1 + num2)
        else:
            exclam = 'Wrong, ' + str(num1 + num2)
```

index.html

```
...
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="int1" value=" {{ num1 }} ">
    <input type="hidden" name="int2" value=" {{ num2 }} ">
    <td><span> {{ num1 }} </span></td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td><span> {{ num2 }} </span></td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td style="padding-top: 6px"> {{ form.as_p }} </td>
</tr>
...
```